# Should I deactivate old APK for Android app on play store?

Tags: android, google-play-console

When I publish a new version of my app in the *Google Play Console*, there is an option to deactivate or keep the old APK. I assumed it was good to keep the old as well for the users who do not have the minimum SDK of the new version (which is different).
Am I wrong?

Is there any side effect to not deactivate the previous APK?
Or any benefit to deactivate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as this old APK works for your users and doesn't bring your review rating down, there is no good reason to remove it. No side effect except possibly having to handle crash reports from multiple versions of your app, but the pain point is on you not your users.